# Making a dictionary having multiple keys using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of metric names.

```py
metrics = {
    'accuracy': accuracy,
    'loss': loss
}
```

I want to create another dictionary that stores the values of the metrics for a set of hierarchical labels. The dictionary is supposed to be something like this:

```
{'c1_accuracy': 0.84, 'c1_loss': 5.67, 'c2_loss': 8.78, 'c2_accuracy': 0.73}
```

I am trying to use something like this

```py
summary_batch = {'c1_{}'.format(metric): metrics['metric'](c1_output, c1_label) for metric in metrics}
```

How can I do it for all the labels (c1, c2, ...) at once?

Edit:
I am trying to solve a hierarchical classification problem where I have two coarse classes (let's say c1 and c2) and one fine class (f). `metrics`
dictionary is just used to store the metrics which are used in the training and evaluation loops. I have separate functions for calculating the metric values. In the above example, `metrics['metric'](c1_output, c1_label) for metric in metrics` will call the `accuracy` and `loss` functions for the true labels (`c1_label`) and model output (`c1_output`).

I want to store these metrics for both coarse classes and the fine class. Is there a way I can do that without using add or writing separate loops for each class?

Comment: What is `accuray`, `loss`, `c1_ouput`, `c1_label` and where are the values `0.84`, `5.67` etc. coming from?

Comment: Shouldn't you rather create a hierarchical structure (dict of dicts, for example) rather than relying on similar names to suggest the structure, and having to manipulate strings in awkward ways to generate the keys?

Comment: What is this in your code `metrics['metric'](c1_output, c1_label)` Can you provide a better sample of your metrics structure?

Comment: @IoaTzimas I have functions for accuracy and loss. `c1_label` is the true label and `c1_output` is the model output. `metrics['metric'](c1_output, c1_label)` will call the function for `c1_output` and `c1_label`. `0.84, 5.67` are the values calculated by the loss and accuracy function.

Comment: Your pseudo-code mixes strings and identifiers, so it is really hard to guess what are the input data to use to build the final dictionary.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Please check the edit. I hope the edit clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know how you obtain the values to fill the dictionary in order to do it while creating it, however, you can create it empty with this loop

```
metrics = {}

for n in range(10):
    key_constructor = 'c{}_{}'
    key_acc = key_constructor.format(n,'accuracy')
    key_loss = key_constructor.format(n,'loss')
    metrics[key_acc] = 0
    metrics[key_loss] = 0
```

Comment: metrics is just a dictionary for storing the desired metrics that I want to calculate for my model. In this case, I have just added accuracy and loss. I have separate functions for calculating accuracy and loss. `metrics['metric'](c1_output, c1_label) for metric in metrics` will call loss and accuracy functions for `c1_output` and `c1_label`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a hierarchy why not using a nested dict?

```py
summuary_batch = {
    "c1": {
        "accuracy": xxx,
        "loss": yyy,
    },
    "c2": {
        "accuracy": zzz,
        "loss": ttt,
    },
}
```